# Can a jlinked runtime be deployed with javapackager?

Tags: javapackager

The instructions to `javapackager` just above Example 2-1 in the Java SE Deployment Guide/[Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG583) state that a jar file is required in the -deploy command.

If I use a modular jar, I get this error message:

> Exception: java.lang.Exception: Error: Modules are not allowed in srcfiles: [dist\tcdmod.jar].

If I use the equivalent non-modular jar, the resulting package includes the complete runtime. But I want to use the reduced runtime I made with jlink that is in the /dist folder.

Can the javapackager command deploy with a jlink-generated runtime? 
How?

The section titled "Customization of the JRE" makes no mention of the `javapackager` command.

The following section "Packaging for Modular Applications" has a following line:

> Use the Java Packager tool to package modular applications as well as non-modular applications.

Is the Java Packager tool distinct from `javapackager`? There are no examples using `javapackager` in this section.

Here is the javapacker command that I used:

```
javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile ToneCircleDrone -srcdir dist -srcfiles tcdplain.jar -appclass com.adonax.tanpura.TCDLaunch -name "ToneCircleDrone" -title "ToneCircleDrone test"
```

The instructions in the javapackager documentation make no mention of the scenario where a jlink runtime is used. There is a Bundler argument -Bruntime but it is only used to point to an installed runtime other than the system default, AFAIK.

Comment: An answer from java-gaming.org shows that it IS possible to connect to a jlink runtime. http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,38682.0.html#msg369300 I will elevate this comment to "answer" if I actually follow through and test it out. I may take the advice to use the jlink directly with 3rd party installer, instead.

Comment: I ended up following an alternate course for deploying a jlink'd application: (1) command line compile, (2) use command line jlink, (3) use Inno Setup 5 to package the distribution created with jlink. All the steps are written up in a walk-through that is posted at java-gaming.org. http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/deployment-and-packaging/38754/msg/370016/view.html#msg370016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `javapackager` provided with JDK 9 and up uses `jlink` to generate the jre image:

> For self-contained applications, the Java Packager for JDK 9 packages 
>   applications with a JDK 9 runtime image generated by the jlink tool. To 
>   package a JDK 8 or JDK 7 JRE with your application, use the JDK 8 Java 
>   Packager.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719

You can even pass arguments to `jlink` using `-BjlinkOptions=<options>`

Additionally, `-Bruntime` is only valid for packages deployed using `-deploy -native jnlp`

For compiling a modular application, instead of `-srcdir`, use `--module-path <dir>`, and then specify the main module using `-m <module name>`.

EDIT: While there is no documentation on `-BjlinkOptions`, it is present in the javapackager source

> jdk.packager/jdk.packager.internal.legacy.JLinkBundlerHelper
>
> https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-10-dev-rt/blob/bf971fe212e9bd14b164e4c1058bc307734e11b1/modules/jdk.packager/src/main/java/jdk/packager/internal/legacy/JLinkBundlerHelper.java#L96

Example Usage: `-BjlinkOptions=compress=2` will make `javapackager` run `jlink` with the `--compress=2` flag, generating the JRE image with Zip Level compression.

Aditionally, running `javapackager` with the flag `-Bverbose=true` will show you exactly which arguments are being passed to `jlink` with a line in the output something like this:

> userArguments = {strip-debug=1 compress=2}

Comment: Answer could be improved with either an example illustrating the use of -BjlinkOptions or link to doc of its usage, and with some context for the -Bruntime comment. Latter has aspects of a non-sequitur as currently written. How does this command relate to the question being answered? The part explaining how to modify a command using -srcdir to using --module-path for modular application is very helpful (assuming it works). But it would be more helpful if complete line example were written using either my example or a javapackager doc scenario example as starting point for the needed changes.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional information in your edits. I can upvote your answer, but I haven't taken the time to test if it works, as I am now using JLink via command line, and packaging with InnoSetup5.

Comment: It seems to me like there has been plenty of opportunity for others to raise questions if there was any issues with this answer. Since there are no objections I'm selecting it as a valid solution. However, I'm doing so with a concern that I have not personally tested it, but have taken another path.